# Typescript: Why can there be several function declarations without function bodies?

Tags: typescript, function, overloading, react-navigation

I found the following Typescript code in [this GitHub issue of the react-navigation library](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/b029e0f6606e9e37e2c67131439aa11da5bf5b8e/packages/routers/src/CommonActions.tsx#L41) which has several function declarations one after the other but only the last declaration contains the function body:

```
export function navigate(
  route:
    | { key: string; params?: object }
    | { name: string; key?: string; params?: object }
): Action;
export function navigate(name: string, params?: object): Action;
export function navigate(...args: any): Action {
  if (typeof args[0] === 'string') {
    // implementation details...
  } else {
    // implementation details...
  }
}
```

How does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Typescript feature called **function overloading** which is [nicely explained here](https://2ality.com/2020/04/typing-functions-typescript.html#overloading).

You can use it to avoid runtime errors in case the types of your parameters contain conditional operators (like the union type `|`).

If you only have a function declaration which contains the function body (and not the other two declarations without function body), it would be a dangerous business, because `any` would allow anything at compile time and only at runtime you'd run into errors depending on which if/else case happens:

```
export function navigate(...args: any): Action {
  if (typeof args[0] === 'string') {
    // implementation details...
  } else {
    // implementation details...
  }
}
```

Clearly here the developer would probably not have used `any` if she/he wouldn't have the other two function declarations in place. But in the [example of Dr. Axel Rauschmayer](https://2ality.com/2020/04/typing-functions-typescript.html#overloading) you see that it would even be problematic if one would add conditionals as parameters instead of `...args: any`, in fact:

```
export function navigate(
  nameOrRoute:
    | string
    | { key: string; params?: object }
    | { name: string; key?: string; params?: object },
  params?: object
): any {
  if (typeof nameOrRoute === 'string') {
    // implementation details...
  } else {
    // implementation details...
  }
}
```

This would allow several combinations of arguments during compile time but would cause errors in some scenarios during runtime.